# Oracle SQL multiple columns aligned to a single range/legend

Tags: sql, oracle, date, multiple-columns

I have an activity table in my application. It has a project ID, an activity ID, a baseline finish date, an actual finish date a planned finish date and a late finish date.

I want to take the count of activity ID for each week of the project in each date column. I then want to take each of these date columns and plot them against each other.

The end result would be a curve that shows the number of activities in week 2 compared to the actual number of activities in week 2 compared to the number of planned activities in week two and the number of late-finish activities in week 2.

I can do this to get the data to show up...

```
SELECT ACTIVITY.PROJECTOBJECTID,
       ACTIVITY.OBJECTID,
       TRUNC(ACTIVITY.BASELINEFINISHDATE,'W')+7 AS BLFIN,
       TRUNC(ACTIVITY.ACTUALFINISHDATE,'W')+7 AS AFIN,
       TRUNC(ACTIVITY.FINISHDATE,'W')+7 AS FIN,
       TRUNC(ACTIVITY.REMAININGLATEFINISHDATE,'W')+7 AS LFIN
  FROM PXRPTUSER.ACTIVITY ACTIVITY
 WHERE (ACTIVITY.PROJECTOBJECTID = :POID)
```

But, now I have four date columns. Ideally I want four count columns with a single date column. Here is a sample of the data I have to work with.

```
PID     AID     BLFIN     AFIN  FIN         LFIN
39987   5874494 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874495 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874496 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874497 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874498 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874499 4/22/2015       4/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874500 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874501 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874502 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874503 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874504 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874505 5/15/2015       5/15/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874506 5/15/2015       5/15/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874507 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874508 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874509 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874510 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874511 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874512 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874513 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874514 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874515 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874516 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874517 4/8/2015        4/8/2015    6/15/2015
39987   5874537 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874538 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874539 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874540 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   2/22/2015
39987   5874542 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874543 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874544 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874545 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874546 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874547 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874548 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874549 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874550 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874551 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874552 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874553 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
39987   5874554 2/22/2015       2/22/2015   6/15/2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query below gives described results. Column WKN is [week number in ISO standard](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php), you may want to change it to something else, eg. 'WW'.
Also if you have dates from different years you have to concatenate year in query (attach year to wkn in bf, af, pf and lf subqueries).

```
with 
bf as (select to_char(blfin, 'iw') wkn, count(aid) cnt 
  from activity group by to_char(blfin, 'iw')),
af as (select to_char(afin, 'iw') wkn, count(aid) cnt 
  from activity group by to_char(afin, 'iw')),
pf as (select to_char(fin, 'iw') wkn, count(aid) cnt 
  from activity group by to_char(fin, 'iw')),
lf as (select to_char(lfin, 'iw') wkn, count(aid) cnt 
  from activity group by to_char(lfin, 'iw'))
select wkn, nvl(bf.cnt, 0) as baseline, nvl(af.cnt, 0) as actual, 
    nvl(pf.cnt, 0) as planned, nvl(lf.cnt, 0) as late
  from bf
    full join af using (wkn)
    full join pf using (wkn)
    full join lf using (wkn)
  where wkn is not null
  order by wkn
```

Results:

```
  WKN BASELINE ACTUAL   PLANNED  LATE
  --- -------- -------- -------- --------
  08        24        0       24        1
  15        14        0       14        0
  17         1        0        1        0
  20         2        0        2        0
  25         0        0        0       40
```

Comment: This is great!! It works exactly as needed. Of course, I made some cosmetic changes. However, I do need the project id to the left of the WKN column on each row. It's possible that I will run this against all open projects and will then group the results in a separate report. I tried altering the full join statement by doing 'full join af using (wkn,pid)' and it didn't work. Any ideas on how I can get there? Thank you very much!

Comment: I was able to make it work. I added the project id to the select statements in the WITH section. Then I added project id to the group by clauses. Then I added project ID before WKN. I then added PID before WKN in the full joins. Presto! Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. Good luck with the project :-)

Comment: One more note: if you ask a question in the future please attach a short table with the expected results, it is very helpful to the person answering.

Comment: So, how would I add a declining total to a column? For example, Baseline column would have WKN 07 = 41, then WKN 08 = 17, then WKN 3 = 12, then WKN 17 = 2, then WKN 20 = 0, then WKN 15 = 0.

Comment: `select wkn, baseline, sum(baseline) over (order by wkn desc) base_decl 
  from my_result order by wkn` ? I used `sum` in its analytic function version here.

Comment: You may want to read more about analytic functions here (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). If you have other doubts, requests, wishes, please form them as separate questions because this site is constructed in question - answer manner, this is not forum. I will gladly help you but this way you have better chance for better and quicker answers.