# Oracle SQL Aggregate minus Running Total

Tags: sql, oracle

Good Day!. I am writing an Oracle SQL statement to create a task burndown chart in a schedule. I have trunc'd the date to weeks and count the number of tasks in the baseline, the number of tasks actually performed and the number of tasks remaining by each week. I then do running totals of each to show me the "burndwown" lines on a line chart.

Here's my trouble... For a project that is partially completed the running total of ACTUAL isn't what I expect it to be. I've tried taking the sum over of baseline and subtracted ACTCNT from it. I've tried taking sum over baseline and subtracted sum over actual from it. None of this gives me what I am looking for. Any ideas and help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is my current output:

```
APOID   WEEK        BASELINE    ACTCNT  ACTUAL  REMCNT  REMAINING
34912   2014/07/29  33          1       25      0   
34912   2014/08/05  32          1       24      0   
34912   2014/08/08  31          1       23      0   
34912   2014/08/15  30          1       22      0   
34912   2014/08/22  30          1       21      0   
34912   2014/08/29  29          0       20      0   
34912   2014/09/15  28          1       20      0   
34912   2014/09/22  27          0       19      0   
34912   2014/09/29  26          1       19      0   
34912   2014/10/08  26          2       18      0   
34912   2014/10/22  23          1       16      0   
34912   2014/10/29  23          1       15      0   
34912   2014/11/05  22          1       14      0   
34912   2014/11/29  21          1       13      0   
34912   2014/12/08  20          2       12      0   
34912   2015/01/08  18          0       10      0   
34912   2015/02/05  17          0       10      0   
34912   2015/02/08  14          1       10      0   
34912   2015/02/15  14          2       9       0   
34912   2015/02/22  11          1       7       0   
34912   2015/03/01  11          4       6       0   
34912   2015/03/08  11          2       2       0   
34912   2015/03/15  8           0               1       11
34912   2015/03/22  8           0               3       10
34912   2015/04/05  6           0               1       7
34912   2015/04/08  5           0               1       6
34912   2015/04/22  4           0               2       5
34912   2015/05/06  3           0               1       3
34912   2015/06/22  2           0               2       2
```

The ACTUAL column is calculating exactly as the SQL says to do. However, with the intent of this burndown chart, Baseline and Actual should start nearly at the same number. So, the first week would show baseline of 33 and because one was completed the first week the Actual column should show 32. Then Remaining should puck up where Actual leaves off with the remaining amounts based on what's actually been completed Like this:

```
APOID   WEEK        BASELINE    ACTCNT  ACTUAL  REMCNT  REMAINING
34912   2014/07/29  33          1       32      0   
34912   2014/08/05  32          1       31      0   
34912   2014/08/08  31          1       30      0   
34912   2014/08/15  30          1       29      0   
34912   2014/08/22  30          1       28      0   
34912   2014/08/29  29          0       28      0   
34912   2014/09/15  28          1       27      0   
34912   2014/09/22  27          0       27      0   
34912   2014/09/29  26          1       26      0   
34912   2014/10/08  26          2       24      0   
34912   2014/10/22  23          1       23      0   
34912   2014/10/29  23          1       22      0   
34912   2014/11/05  22          1       21      0   
34912   2014/11/29  21          1       20      0   
34912   2014/12/08  20          2       18      0   
34912   2015/01/08  18          0       18      0   
34912   2015/02/05  17          0       18      0   
34912   2015/02/08  14          1       17      0   
34912   2015/02/15  14          2       15      0   
34912   2015/02/22  11          1       14      0   
34912   2015/03/01  11          4       10      0   
34912   2015/03/08  11          2       8       0   
34912   2015/03/15  8           0               1       11
34912   2015/03/22  8           0               3       10
34912   2015/04/05  6           0               1       7
34912   2015/04/08  5           0               1       6
34912   2015/04/22  4           0               2       5
34912   2015/05/06  3           0               1       3
34912   2015/06/22  2           0               2       2
```

```sql
SELECT
    APOID,
    WEEK,
    SUM(BASELINE) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK DESC) BASELINE,
    ACTUAL AS ACTCNT,
    (CASE
      WHEN WEEK < DD THEN SUM(ACTUAL) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK DESC)
      ELSE NULL
    END) AS ACTUAL,
    REMAINING AS REMCNT,
    (CASE
      WHEN WEEK >= DD THEN SUM(REMAINING) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK DESC)
      ELSE NULL
    END) AS REMAINING
FROM
(
WITH 
BF AS (SELECT A.PROJECTOBJECTID AS APOID, COUNT (A.OBJECTID) AS CNT, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.BASELINEFINISHDATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS WEEK, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.DATADATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS DD
  FROM PXRPTUSER.ACTIVITY A
 WHERE (A.PROJECTOBJECTID = :POID) AND A.TYPE IN ('Task Dependent','Resource Dependent')
GROUP BY A.PROJECTOBJECTID, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.BASELINEFINISHDATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.DATADATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD')),

AF AS (SELECT A.PROJECTOBJECTID AS APOID, COUNT (A.OBJECTID) AS CNT, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.ACTUALFINISHDATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS WEEK, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.DATADATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS DD
  FROM PXRPTUSER.ACTIVITY A
 WHERE (A.PROJECTOBJECTID = :POID) AND A.TYPE IN ('Task Dependent','Resource Dependent')
GROUP BY A.PROJECTOBJECTID, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.ACTUALFINISHDATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.DATADATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD')),

PF AS (SELECT A.PROJECTOBJECTID AS APOID, COUNT (A.OBJECTID) AS CNT, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS WEEK, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.DATADATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS DD
  FROM PXRPTUSER.ACTIVITY A
 WHERE (A.PROJECTOBJECTID = :POID) AND A.TYPE IN ('Task Dependent','Resource Dependent')
GROUP BY A.PROJECTOBJECTID, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.DATADATE,'W')+7,'YYYY/MM/DD'))

SELECT
  APOID, WEEK, DD, NVL(BF.CNT, 0) AS BASELINE, NVL(AF.CNT, 0) AS ACTUAL, 
    NVL(PF.CNT, 0) AS REMAINING
  FROM BF
    FULL JOIN AF USING (APOID,WEEK,DD)
    FULL JOIN PF USING (APOID,WEEK,DD)
  WHERE WEEK IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY WEEK
) R
ORDER BY WEEK
```

Here is the data:

```
APOID   OBJECTID    BASELINEFINISHDATE  DATADATE    ACTUALFINISHDATE    REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE    TYPE
34912   4949302     3/18/2015           3/9/2015                        3/18/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949322     1/30/2015           3/9/2015    2/19/2015                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949323     9/17/2014           3/9/2015    9/26/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949324     1/30/2015           3/9/2015                        3/13/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949348     3/6/2015            3/9/2015    2/25/2015                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949349     3/6/2015            3/9/2015    3/5/2015                                        Task Dependent
34912   4949351     1/2/2015            3/9/2015    2/13/2015                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949353     2/13/2015           3/9/2015    3/2/2015                                        Task Dependent
34912   4949355     1/30/2015           3/9/2015    2/23/2015                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949400     2/10/2015           3/9/2015    2/10/2015                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949681     2/13/2015           3/9/2015    2/3/2015                                        Task Dependent
34912   4949286     10/29/2014          3/9/2015    10/29/2014                                      Task Dependent
34912   4949287     4/2/2015            3/9/2015                        4/2/2015                    Task Dependent
34912   4949289     7/22/2014           3/9/2015    7/22/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949321     10/1/2014           3/9/2015    10/16/2014                                      Task Dependent
34912   4949365     10/27/2014          3/9/2015    10/27/2014                                      Task Dependent
34912   4949372     3/6/2015            3/9/2015                        3/16/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949374     4/16/2015           3/9/2015                        4/16/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949375     3/20/2015           3/9/2015                        4/15/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949377     9/10/2014           3/9/2015    8/20/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949395     12/3/2014           3/9/2015    12/4/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949396     3/31/2015           3/9/2015                        3/31/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949397     6/19/2015           3/9/2015                        6/19/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949399     4/30/2015           3/9/2015                        4/30/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   4949454     11/26/2014          3/9/2015    11/26/2014                                      Task Dependent
34912   4949456     10/6/2014           3/9/2015    10/3/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949460     8/27/2014           3/9/2015    8/8/2014                                        Task Dependent
34912   4949275     8/1/2014            3/9/2015    8/5/2014                                        Task Dependent
34912   4949277     7/30/2014           3/9/2015    7/30/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949278     12/3/2014           3/9/2015    12/3/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949457     8/20/2014           3/9/2015    9/10/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949458     10/1/2014           3/9/2015    10/2/2014                                       Task Dependent
34912   4949535     6/19/2015           3/9/2015                        6/19/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   5914141                         3/9/2015    2/27/2015                                       Task Dependent
34912   5931635                         3/9/2015                        3/16/2015                   Task Dependent
34912   5914140                         3/9/2015    2/23/2015                                       Task Dependent
```

Here is the CREATE TABLE query...

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEMP
(
  APOID                     NUMBER,
  OBJECTID                  NUMBER,
  BASELINEFINISHDATE        DATE,
  DATADATE                  DATE,
  REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE  DATE,
  TYPE                      VARCHAR(24)
)
```

Here is the INSERT query...

```sql
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949302, TO_DATE('03/18/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/18/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949322, TO_DATE('01/30/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/19/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949323, TO_DATE('09/17/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('09/26/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949324, TO_DATE('01/30/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/13/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949348, TO_DATE('03/06/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/25/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949349, TO_DATE('03/06/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/05/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949351, TO_DATE('01/02/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/13/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949353, TO_DATE('02/13/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/02/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949355, TO_DATE('01/30/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/23/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949400, TO_DATE('02/10/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/10/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949681, TO_DATE('02/13/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/03/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949275, TO_DATE('08/01/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('08/05/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949277, TO_DATE('07/30/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('07/30/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949278, TO_DATE('12/03/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/03/2014 17:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949286, TO_DATE('10/29/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('10/29/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949287, TO_DATE('04/02/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('04/02/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949289, TO_DATE('07/22/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('07/22/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949321, TO_DATE('10/01/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('10/16/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949365, TO_DATE('10/27/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('10/27/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949372, TO_DATE('03/06/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/16/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949374, TO_DATE('04/16/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('04/16/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949375, TO_DATE('03/20/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('04/15/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949377, TO_DATE('09/10/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('08/20/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949395, TO_DATE('12/03/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/04/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949396, TO_DATE('03/31/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/31/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949397, TO_DATE('06/19/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('06/19/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949399, TO_DATE('04/30/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('04/30/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949454, TO_DATE('11/26/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('11/26/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949456, TO_DATE('10/06/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('10/03/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949457, TO_DATE('08/20/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('09/10/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949458, TO_DATE('10/01/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('10/02/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949460, TO_DATE('08/27/2014 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('08/08/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, BASELINEFINISHDATE, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, 
    TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 4949535, TO_DATE('06/19/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('06/19/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 5914140, TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/23/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, DATADATE, ACTUALFINISHDATE, TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 5914141, TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('02/27/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Task Dependent');
Insert into TEMP
   (APOID, OBJECTID, DATADATE, REMAININGEARLYFINISHDATE, TYPE)
 Values
   (34912, 5931635, TO_DATE('03/09/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('03/16/2015 16:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Task Dependent');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Is the create table for TEMP supposed to ACTIVITY? One of the column names doesn't match your main query at the moment. It's a little hard to follow when it isn't consistent.

Comment: Also, the ACTUALFINISHDATE column is missing from your create table statement.

Comment: Is the ACTUAL output column really supposed to be calculated on whatever the BASELINE is, minus whatever was actually finished (ie. you don't need to find the cumulative count of the actually finished items)?

Comment: OOPS! I am sorry. I was juggling too many things at once. TEMP is supposed to be ACTIVITY.

Comment: Yes, I missed the actualfinishdate on the create table statement. Sorry.

Comment: @Boneist, Not really. ACTUAL is a reflection of activity counts that have actual finish dates populated. I just couldn't get it to sum properly. I think Alex Poole figured out that I wasn't doing the windows right. That's a new topic for me. So, I need to crack the book open and look a little more. As soon as I understand it I will test it and mark the correct answer.

Comment: @Alex Poole Thanks. I will look into windows and try to understand them. It's a new topic for me.

Comment: I've seen these data [somewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652040/oracle-sql-multiple-columns-aligned-to-a-single-range-legend/) ;-)

Comment: @ponder stibbons  Yes, yes, yes... Line upon line. I'm learning a huge amount here. Thanks to this wonderful community.

Comment: I'm sorry, did not mean to point out to you about anything. I appreciate the construction of your new questions and the fact that you learn. I just mentioned that I once fought with this data, which could be useful in the creation of this response. Answer was given, you learnt somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried taking the sum over of baseline and subtracted ACTCNT from it. I've tried taking sum over baseline and subtracted sum over actual from it.

It looks like you were summing over the wrong windows for both approaches. You need the sum of the baselines across the whole range, which you can get from the 
unbounded preceding/following window; and the sum of the actual counts has to be in date-ascending order, not descending:

```
SELECT
    APOID,
    WEEK,
    SUM(BASELINE) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK DESC) BASELINE,
    ACTUAL AS ACTCNT,
    (CASE
      WHEN WEEK < DD THEN
        SUM(BASELINE) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK
          RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
            - SUM(ACTUAL) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK)
      ELSE NULL
    END) AS ACTUAL,
    REMAINING AS REMCNT,
    (CASE
      WHEN WEEK >= DD THEN
        SUM(REMAINING) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK DESC)
      ELSE NULL
    END) AS REMAINING
FROM
(
...
```

Which gets:

```
     APOID WEEK         BASELINE     ACTCNT     ACTUAL     REMCNT  REMAINING
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     34912 2014/07/29         33          1         32          0            
     34912 2014/08/05         32          1         31          0            
     34912 2014/08/08         31          1         30          0            
     34912 2014/08/15         30          1         29          0            
     34912 2014/08/22         30          1         28          0            
     34912 2014/08/29         29          0         28          0            
     34912 2014/09/15         28          1         27          0            
     34912 2014/09/22         27          0         27          0            
     34912 2014/09/29         26          1         26          0            
     34912 2014/10/08         26          2         24          0            
     34912 2014/10/22         23          1         23          0            
     34912 2014/10/29         23          1         22          0            
     34912 2014/11/05         22          1         21          0            
     34912 2014/11/29         21          1         20          0            
     34912 2014/12/08         20          2         18          0            
     34912 2015/01/08         18          0         18          0            
     34912 2015/02/05         17          0         18          0            
     34912 2015/02/08         14          1         17          0            
     34912 2015/02/15         14          2         15          0            
     34912 2015/02/22         11          1         14          0            
     34912 2015/03/01         11          4         10          0            
     34912 2015/03/08         11          2          8          0            
     34912 2015/03/15          8          0                     1         11 
     34912 2015/03/22          8          0                     3         10 
     34912 2015/04/05          6          0                     1          7 
     34912 2015/04/08          5          0                     1          6 
     34912 2015/04/22          4          0                     2          5 
     34912 2015/05/06          3          0                     1          3 
     34912 2015/06/22          2          0                     2          2 

 29 rows selected
```

Your choice of 'W' for the truncation target seems strange though; you're aligning to the week number within the calendar month, which doesn't seem very help. For grouping purposes, WW or IW might make more sense.

I broke this down slightly differently trying to understand what you're doing; this is basically the same approach but has one more level than it really needs now, and gets the same answer with 'W' week groups; for comparison here it is with 'IW' week groups:

```
WITH b AS (
  SELECT projectobjectid, objectid, datadate, baselinefinishdate,
    TRUNC(baselinefinishdate, 'IW') + 7 AS week
  FROM temp
  WHERE projectobjectid = :poid
  AND type IN ('Task Dependent','Resource Dependent')
  AND baselinefinishdate IS NOT NULL
),
a AS (
  SELECT projectobjectid, objectid, datadate, actualfinishdate,
    TRUNC(actualfinishdate, 'IW') + 7 AS week
  FROM temp
  WHERE projectobjectid = :poid
  AND type IN ('Task Dependent','Resource Dependent')
  AND actualfinishdate IS NOT NULL
),
r AS (
  SELECT projectobjectid, objectid, datadate, remainingearlyfinishdate,
    TRUNC(remainingearlyfinishdate, 'IW') + 7 AS week
  FROM temp
  WHERE projectobjectid = :poid
  AND type IN ('Task Dependent','Resource Dependent')
  AND remainingearlyfinishdate IS NOT NULL
),
w AS (
  SELECT projectobjectid, objectid, datadate, week FROM b
  UNION SELECT projectobjectid, objectid, datadate, week FROM a
  UNION SELECT projectobjectid, objectid, datadate, week FROM r
),
s AS (
  SELECT w.projectobjectid, w.week, w.datadate,
    COUNT(b.objectid) AS bcnt, COUNT(a.objectid) AS acnt, COUNT(r.objectid) AS rcnt
  FROM w
  LEFT JOIN b ON b.projectobjectid = w.projectobjectid
    AND b.objectid = w.objectid AND b.datadate = w.datadate AND b.week = w.week
  LEFT JOIN a ON a.projectobjectid = w.projectobjectid
    AND a.objectid = w.objectid AND a.datadate = w.datadate AND a.week = w.week
  LEFT JOIN r ON r.projectobjectid = w.projectobjectid
    AND r.objectid = w.objectid AND r.datadate = w.datadate AND r.week = w.week
  GROUP BY w.projectobjectid, w.datadate, w.week
)
SELECT projectobjectid AS apoid, TO_CHAR(week, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS week,
  SUM(bcnt) OVER (PARTITION BY projectobjectid ORDER BY week DESC) AS baseline,
  SUM(acnt) OVER (PARTITION BY projectobjectid, week) AS actcnt,
  CASE WHEN week < datadate THEN
    SUM(bcnt) OVER (PARTITION BY projectobjectid ORDER BY week
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
      - SUM(acnt) OVER (PARTITION BY projectobjectid ORDER BY week) END AS actual,
  SUM(rcnt) OVER (PARTITION BY projectobjectid, week) AS remcnt,
  CASE WHEN week >= datadate THEN
    SUM(rcnt) OVER (PARTITION BY projectobjectid ORDER BY week DESC) END AS remaining
FROM s
ORDER BY projectobjectid, week;

     APOID WEEK         BASELINE     ACTCNT     ACTUAL     REMCNT  REMAINING
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     34912 2014/07/28         33          1         32          0            
     34912 2014/08/04         32          1         31          0            
     34912 2014/08/11         30          2         29          0            
     34912 2014/08/25         30          1         28          0            
     34912 2014/09/01         29          0         28          0            
     34912 2014/09/15         28          1         27          0            
     34912 2014/09/22         27          0         27          0            
     34912 2014/09/29         26          1         26          0            
     34912 2014/10/06         26          2         24          0            
     34912 2014/10/13         24          0         24          0            
     34912 2014/10/20         23          1         23          0            
     34912 2014/11/03         23          2         21          0            
     34912 2014/12/01         21          1         20          0            
     34912 2014/12/08         20          2         18          0            
     34912 2015/01/05         18          0         18          0            
     34912 2015/02/02         17          0         18          0            
     34912 2015/02/09         14          1         17          0            
     34912 2015/02/16         14          2         15          0            
     34912 2015/02/23         11          1         14          0            
     34912 2015/03/02         11          4         10          0            
     34912 2015/03/09         11          2                     0         11 
     34912 2015/03/16          8          0                     1         11 
     34912 2015/03/23          8          0                     3         10 
     34912 2015/04/06          6          0                     2          7 
     34912 2015/04/20          4          0                     2          5 
     34912 2015/05/04          3          0                     1          3 
     34912 2015/06/22          2          0                     2          2 

 27 rows selected
```